# Delete json array elements based on values of subarray

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following json file which contains this array structure:

```
{
  "outer": [
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "value": "val1"
        },
        {
          "value": "val3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "value": "val2"
        },
        {
          "value": "val1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "value": "val2"
        },
        {
          "value": "val1"
        },
        {
          "value": "val3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the `inner` array from the `outer` array whose elements have specific values and and is of certain length. E.g., if I want to delete the `inner` array which contains values `"val1"` and `"val2"` the result should be:

```
{
  "outer": [
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "value": "val1"
        },
        {
          "value": "val3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "inner": [
        {
          "value": "val2"
        },
        {
          "value": "val1"
        },
        {
          "value": "val3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried

```
jq 'del( .outer[]|select(.inner[0].value == "val1"))'
```

but I do not know how to check for the second condition, the length and on top of that the values may appear in any order.

Comment: The keys are always "outer", "inner" and "value"?

Comment: @nautical: for your consideration, there's an _alternative_ solution for JSON manipulation in your ask - based on a `walk-path` unix utility `jtc` (developed by me): `<file.json jtc -pw'[value]:<val1>:[-2][value]:<val2>[-2]<>f[2]<>F'`. Let me know if you like me to elaborate on the utility usage in the separate answer.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for the offer but I am not at liberty to install new software on the system. I am stuck with `jq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq` filter you are looking for is:

```
del(.outer[] | select(.inner | map(.value) | sort == ["val1", "val2"]))
```

`.inner | map(.value)` produces an array that contains the values associated to the `value` key from all objects contained by `.inner`.

`sort` is needed because `==` does a one-to-one comparison of arrays. This way it matches the objects contained in `.inner` no matter their order. Of course, you have to use a sorted array on the right-hand side (i.e. `["val1", "val2"]` and not `["val2", "val1"]`).

See it [in action](https://jqplay.org/s/FDrKj8AIf2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it produces the desired result on  `jqplay.org` it aborts with an error on the command line: `Invalid path expression with result {"inner":[{"value":"val2"}...`. My `jq` version is: `jq-1.5`. Do I need a newer one for the solution to work?

Comment: Indeed, it works with version 1.6 but it doesn't work with version 1.5 :-(

Comment: I upgraded to version 1.6 and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, in version 1.6 [`del()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) is more relaxed and accepts not only paths, as described in the documentations, but also objects. In version 1.5 it doesn't accept objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which should work on all versions of jq at least from version 1.3 onwards, and which is readily adapted to take into account additional criteria, as mentioned in the Q:

```
# A helper function for defining the retention criteria.
# It is assumed that the input is the array to be checked and that
# `match` is already sorted.
def retain( match ): (map(.value) | sort) != match;

.outer |= map( select( .inner | retain( ["val1", "val2"] ) ))
```