# unix - delete a string from a json file where maching pattern

Tags: json, unix, sed

I have these data in my json file:

```
{
    "software": [{
            "softwareId": "61426b91-0403-4e72-8bc3-bee6e4aabf00",
            "softwareURL": "https://mydns/download/test.json",
            "softwareName": "file1",
            "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
            "softwareType": "FILE",
            "signature": "yTzilsyq+0qVuioDD8cNT8zAtKt+qGTJ9aQ=="
        }, {
            "softwareId": "716a259b-c90b-47c8-856a-25e6bca61bc8",
            "softwareURL": "https://mydns/download/test1.json",
            "softwareName": "file2",
            "softwareVersion": "2.0.0",
            "softwareType": "FILE",
            "signature": "vjmTQXgCxsw/q7Wz3a4g6N5Ht+Bhumo1acw=="
        }, {
            "softwareId": "c72644d5-6024-4783-a520-20bf39c8ea18",
            "softwareURL": "https://mydns/download/test2.json",
            "softwareName": "folder",
            "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
            "softwareType": "FOLDER",
            "signature": "hb35vQdVuhL7pRvRmV1OdGXYFLcpC4UKn0w=="
        }
    ]
}
```

I want delete the json structure {} where "softwareType": "FILE" and "softwareName": "file2".
This should be the result:

```
{
    "software": [{
            "softwareId": "61426b91-0403-4e72-8bc3-bee6e4aabf00",
            "softwareURL": "https://mydns/download/test.json",
            "softwareName": "file1",
            "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
            "softwareType": "FILE",
            "signature": "yTzilsyq+0qVuioDD8cNT8zAtKt+qGTJ9aQ=="
        }, {
            "softwareId": "c72644d5-6024-4783-a520-20bf39c8ea18",
            "softwareURL": "https://mydns/download/test2.json",
            "softwareName": "folder",
            "softwareVersion": "1.0.0",
            "softwareType": "FOLDER",
            "signature": "hb35vQdVuhL7pRvRmV1OdGXYFLcpC4UKn0w=="
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you help me to do that with a sed command or like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this reliably with sed or any other tool that treats the file as just a bunch of lines of data.  Use a tool like `jq` to manipulate your JSON data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete json array elements based on values of subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854868/delete-json-array-elements-based-on-values-of-subarray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres an easy way to do this using `jq`, and it has been answered before: [Delete json array elements based on values of subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854868/delete-json-array-elements-based-on-values-of-subarray)

Answer (score 0):

Using jq:

```
jq '.software[] | select(.softwareType!="FILE" or .softwareName!="file2")' file.json
```

Use select to find where the softwareType is not "FILE" or softwareName is not "file2"